# Proving the binomial coefficients by induction (half-done, but need help)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Defining the binomial coefficients $n \choose k$ as follows, 
i) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\binom{n}{0} = \binom{n}{ n} = 1$
(ii) for all $2 \leq n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $ 1 \leq k \leq n-1, \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}  + \binom{n-1}{k}$
Use induction to prove that

$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{ n!}{(n-k)!k!}$

I have done significant work on this problem, and to learn better, I would prefer if people could first look at my work and help me patch in the holes (I'm trying to induct for both k and n, and I'm missing half of each proof.) Also, is it necessary to induct for both k and n?
**Here's what I did:**

First, let k=1. Now for all $2 \leq n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $\binom{n}{1} = \binom{n-1}{0}+\binom{n-1}{1}$

According to our definition, $\binom{n-1}{0}=1$

Also, $\binom{n-1}{1}=n-1$

Thus, $\binom{n}{1}=1+(n-1)=n$, bu definition.

By the formula we want to prove, $\binom{n}{1} = $\frac{n}{(n-1)} = n$

So the formula holds for $k=1$.

**Struggled with showing that it holds for $k$ and $k+1$. Can you choose $k-1$ and $k$ instead? Is that any easier?**

On the other hand, if the formula holds for $\binom{n}{k}$, we can write $\binom{n+1}{k}$ in terms of the formula for $\binom{n}{k}$.

We have that $\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}$.

Substituting for $\binom{n}{k}$, we get

$$\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k-1} + \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$

Similarly, we can write $\binom{n}{k-1}$ as a quotient of factorials (since we know that varying $k$ values hold the formula for all $1 \leq k \leq n-1$), as follows:

$$\binom{n+1}{k}=\frac{ n!}{(n-[k-1])!(k-1)!} + \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$

By algebraic manipulation *(should I explain in more detail?)*, we get

$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1-k)!k!}$, the same as our formula would give us for $\binom{n+1}{k}$. Thus, if the formula holds for $\binom{n}{k}$, it also holds for $\binom{n+1}{k}$.

**I had trouble showing that it held for $n=1$.**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint

\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k} & =\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n-k\right)!\left(k-1\right)!}+\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n-1-k\right)!k!}\\
 & =\frac{\left(n-1\right)!k}{\left(n-k\right)!k!}+\frac{\left(n-1\right)!\left(n-k\right)}{\left(n-k\right)!k!}\\
 & =\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n-k\right)!k!}\left(k+n-k\right)\\
 & =\frac{n!}{\left(n-k\right)!k!}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, par. I don't 100% understand where this fits into induction. Can you use this to show it works for n and k, and then you repeat it with (n+1) and (k+1)? Thanks!

Comment: Suppose the claim holds for $n-1$ and all $k < n$. Show that it holds for $n$ and all $k \leq n$.